# How a Bounded Context correlates with the design of a Microservice?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I'm doing the analysis of a Monolithic Architecture to migrate to Microservices Architecture and I imagine that a Microservice is an implementation of Bounded Context of a Domain.

My question is whether I'm tackling this the right way or I'm scramble the architecture, how does a Bounded Context correlate with a Microservice?

Comment: Although it doesn't give a hard and fast answer, this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFCgXH7DwxM) by Eric Evans sheds very helpful light on the relationship between BC's and microservices.

Comment: Yes, it's a very instructive video and it reminds me that I need to study certain points of DDD more in depth, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually bounded context = 1 micro-service., though its not a rule. But it all depends on you domain. Also think about Single responsibility principle, you services or micro-services should be responsible for one and only one thing. So for example "sales" could be one bounded context and "billing" could be another, however customer is not a bounded context, its an object you might use in both sales and billing. Services usually will should communicate with each other using domain events, such as "sale completed", "bill generated" etc etc. This is not a complete answer but just a pointer to further exploration.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, this helped me realize that one problem I have isn't the Microservice Architecture but the Domain Model that needs to be better specified, Thanks.

Comment: @william If it answered your question please can you mark the answer as answered.